# Null Value for record after getting id from a map of ids and accounts

Tags: custom-controller, aggregateresult, null

The system.debug shows that the id for TempAcct is associated with the correct id after a.get('Franchise__c'), but NewAcct = null. The debug shows that the id was mapped correctly to filterIds, and it's the same id in the aggregateResult.

So why does `TempAcct = IdAccount.get((Id)(a.get('Franchise__c')));` work but `NewAcct = filterIds.get((Id)(a.get('Franchise__c')));` not work?

Controller:

```
public with sharing class inspectionsDashboard {

    public inspectionsDashboard() {

        soql = 'SELECT Name,BillingState FROM Account WHERE Id IN : Ids';

        for(AggregateResult a : Result) {
            Ids.add((Id)a.get('Franchise__c'));
        }

        runQuery();

        for(Account a : AcctList) {
            IdAccount.put(a.Id, a);            
        }

        for(AggregateResult a : Result) {
            Account TempAcct = new Account();            
            TempAcct = IdAccount.get((Id)(a.get('Franchise__c')));
            SummaryList.add(new Summary(a, TempAcct.Name, TempAcct.BillingState)); 

        }
    }


    public void runQuery() {

          AcctList = Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20');
    }


    public PageReference runSearch() {

        Account NewAcct = new Account();
        filterIds = new Map<Id,Account>();
        soql = 'SELECT Name,BillingState FROM Account WHERE Id In: Ids';

        runQuery();

        for(Account a : AcctList) {
            filterIds.put(a.id, a);            
        }

        for(AggregateResult a : Result) {  

            system.debug('Result is ' +a);
            NewAcct = filterIds.get((Id)(a.get('Franchise__c')));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you clean up unnecessary code which is not relevant to your question

Comment: Yes I believe the above is necessary.

Comment: Your query contains a `limit 20` clause. There's a possibility that your query does not return Accounts whose Ids are in `filterIds` for that reason.

Comment: I changed the limit to 120 and the result was the same

Comment: I would push you, like Santanu, to cut this down to a minimum reproduction. It's a lot of code to wade through and your description is not entirely clear.

Comment: Ok I've trimmed it down some more

Comment: Ok I've just realized that it NewAcct != null when I begin the name query with a different account name, but it should work the same for both names.

Comment: But if I add system.debug('Account Name is ' + NewAcct.Name) to the last for loop, when I query for that same name that previously would show as the name for NewAcct without that one line, I get the error message: attempting to de-reference a null object.

Comment: Can you remove the limit entirely? Also Franchise__c is a lookup to account right?

Comment: I did remove the limit entirely and it made no difference. Franchise__c is a lookup to the Account. Correct. But this field is actually on a related object, inspection__c, and it's being queried here through the aggregateresult list 'Result' that queries aggregations of that inspection__c object.